# MVC Razor binding to a list within a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a list of objects with a list of objects inside and i'm trying to bind to them in a form but the sublist is coming back as null when I submit. I was hoping someone might be able to spot where i'm going wrong/ or if this is even possible.

My code looks like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities.Count; i++)
{
<div id="@("panel" + i)" class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@i" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActNo)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].Method)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].Area)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].Exposure)
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="@i" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul id="@("actSyms" + i)" class="Symbols">
                @for (var x = 0; x < Model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms.Count; x++)
                {
                    <li class="actSymItem">
                        <a onclick=" DeleteActSym(this); return false; " href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms[x].CommCode)
                        @Html.Image("../Content/Images/Symbols/" + Model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms[x].SymbCode + ".jpg", Model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms[x].SymbCode, "dd")
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms[x].SymbCode)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlgorithmOutput.Activities[i].ActSyms[x].Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { rows = 3, cols = 12, @class = "form-control" } })
                    </li>
                }
                <a href="#" id="@i" onclick=" NewActSym(this); return false; ">Add</a>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Comment: The view looks OK. Does `ActSyms` have a getter/setter?

Comment: it could be interesting to see how you feed you list in the controller, maybe something is missing.

Comment: It was just missing a getter/setter in the model. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Just require the getter/setter in the model, with thanks to Stephen Muecke for pointing that out